# Can I install a program on a different partition than Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-vista

I've just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition with Windows Vista on the other side.  I'm wondering if I can use space on the Windows partition for programs in Ubuntu?

Comment: It depends: which programs. Ubuntu doesn't separate programs and put them in nice little segregated areas like Windows. Instead everything is smushed together. You could rip apart a .deb file and symlink all the files though (but windows'd probably mess it all up)

Comment: Even if you could (and you probably could, with enough effort), I can't see why you would, and I'm sure you would regret it when it came time to update/upgrade.

Comment: Use portable apps like Portable apps. They work from both Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Yes! you can. Just add following to your `~/.bashrc` file.
`export PATH="/path/to/your/program:$PATH"`
After adding don't forget to restart your terminal or just execute `exec bash`.